# how union multiple real time databases in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How union multiple real time databases in firebase?  I would like to union multiple databases and order them by date. Is it possible?

I have stored different types of notifications in different tables. Now I have to show all of the notifications in one page and have to do pagination too. Only possible way, I think, is to union all the tables. Is it possible?
Or should I restructure the database and put all types of notifications in one database?
These notification types are like (comments, different types of requests, forums, poll notifications etc.)

Comment: I believe this is not possible.